# Ruby program to print first n Fibonacci Seqeunce

Tags: ruby, fibonacci

Newbie here! Trying to implement a program to print the first 20 Fibonacci numbers in Ruby. I've managed to create a program which generates the nth number, but I want to produce all from 0 through to 20.

Is there a simple way to do this or do I need to rewrite the whole program?

**CURRENT CODE**

```
def fib(n)
   if n < 1 
     return 0 
       elsif n == 1
     return 1 
    else fib(n-2) + fib(n-1)
  end 
end

puts fib(20)
```

CURRENT OUTPUT EXAMPLE

```
6765
```

DESIRED OUTCOME

```
0
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
89
144
233
377
610
987
1597
2584
4181
6765
```

Comment: You could run your code in a loop, e.g. `0.upto(20) { |i| puts fib(i) }`

Comment: @Stefan oh _that_ sounds efficient. Not.

Comment: @matt I wrote it and understand it. The steps in my code are as follows;

1. if n is less than 1, return 0
2. else, if n is equal to 1, return 1
3. else, do n-2 + n-1

Comment: Ok. So when returning any value from `fib`, you need to print it. — Incidentally your code is very inefficient too. Think about the expression `fib(n-2) + fib(n-1)`. The second term involves calculating the first term, so you are doing the entire recursion twice even though you don't have to. Hint: pass more information into `fib`.

Comment: @matt without memoization that recursive approach is already inefficient.

Comment: Regarding the printing – you have to print any value returned from `fib` that hasn't been printed already. The problem here is that you are re-calculating the same values over and over again.

Comment: @Stefan I just said that, sort of.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone - You are awesome. I'm with you and am going to spend some more time and play around with it until I find my own solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Printing each value is easier with a button-up approach where you start at `0` and `1` and calculate each following value based on its predecessors, e.g.:

```
i, j = 0, 1

puts i
puts j

21.times do
  k = i + j
  puts k
  i, j = j, k
end
```

You could turn the above into an [`Enumerator`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Enumerator.html):

```
fib = Enumerator.new do |y|
  i, j = 0, 1

  y << i
  y << j

  loop do
    k = i + j
    y << k
    i, j = j, k
  end
end
```

Which will generate the sequence:

```
fib.take(21)
#=> [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144,
#    233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765]
```

Answer (score 3):

At the moment you only print the last value returned by your method (`fib(20)`) but not the result of all intermediate steps.

An easy way would be to cache all intermediate results in a hash data structure. This would also improve performance for big `n` because you do not need to recalculate many values over and over again.

Then you can just print out all results from `0` to `n`:

```
def cached_fib(n)
  @cache ||= Hash.new do |cache, n| 
    @cache[n] = n < 2 ? n : cache[n-1] + cache[n-2]
  end

  @cache[n]
end

def fib(n)
  0.upto(n) { |i| puts cached_fib(i) }
end

fib(20)
#=> 0
    1
    1
    2
    3
    5
    8
    13
    21
    34
    55
    89
    144
    233
    377
    610
    987
    1597
    2584
    4181
    6765
```

Comment: You can omit the condition inside the dynamic hash by providing the initial values explicitly, e.g. `Hash.new { |h, n| h[n] = h[n-2] + h[n-1] }.merge(0 => 0, 1 => 1)`